# Dynamic positioned hover popup

Tags: jquery, popup, hover

How to create dynamic positioned hover popup, that can change direction from left to right depending on parent indent without tooltip plugins

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="visible">visible content</div>
    <div class="hidden">hidden content</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.main > .visible').hover(function () {
    $('.hidden').show();
}, 
function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();
});
```

example (when hover over poster popup change the direction)
http://www.ivi.ru/videos/all/all/all/by_new/?year_from=2010&year_to=2012

Comment: if you have a defined number of elements per row and defined size of the popup (as in the example), you know if the popup will fit the page and you can align it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this, you can do this in CSS.

Set .main to `relative` and .visible/.hidden to `absolute` so you can position .hidden "outside" .main, then have it displayed when you hover over .main.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZSk/1/

```
.main {
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
background:#ff0000;   
}
.main:hover .hidden {
display:block;   
}
.visible {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100px;
height:100px;   
}
.hidden {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:100px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:none;
background:#aaaaff;   
}
```

Comment: this is my cuurent code) the problem is is that the hidden text goes beyond the container http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZSk/2/
in need a small scipt, that automatically define the offset and set the direction of hidden text

Comment: Well, then change the position for the last item in each row: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZSk/7/ Where 3 = (# columns) and 2 = (# columns - 1). I also updated the z-index;

Comment: like a workable solution, but it requires a set number of rows and columns, I would like a more versatile solution

Comment: :| Okay, then this gets the number of columns based on the size of .container and .main: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZSk/8/

Comment: made some changes to fully control the width via CSS http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZSk/9/
it seems works for me, thanks