# Dynamically positioned popup definitions that show on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am looking to create popup definitions that show when a div is hovered over. My site will show detailed specifications on cameras, I would like it when the user hovers over the megapixel class named '.mp' then a small popup shows above with a short definition. One of the key ways I would like it to work is so I can add the class '.mp' on to any existing div/class and when it is hovered over then the popup shows above that div/class also allowing me to reuse definitions in multiple places around the site.

I am looking for the most efficient way possible, I know how to do what I'm looking to do however my way is very inefficient and cumbersome.

This is how I lay out the specifications are layed out on my site, in photoshop I have just added the type of effect I would like to receive on hover.

[image]

The specs are outputted all with PHP from my database, each one has the wrapper '.spec_item' I currently store the names of the specs in an array which can be added onto each div in a for loop

```
$sensor_db = array("mp", "sensor_size", "sensor_type", "light_sensitivity");
```

This creates divs as such:

```
<div class="spec_item mp">
    12.9
</div>
<div class="spec_item sensor_size">
    0.95X
</div>
<div class="spec_item sensor_type">
    APS-C
</div>
```

When the user hovers over any div with the name '.mp' for example, then the definition shows below it in a little popup as shown in my picture example. To achieve this, I know I could store all the definitions in another array and just have the div as display none and on hover display block, however if i did this, I could not simply add the class '.mp' onto any div and it show the definition, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I appreciate any help or direction to how I could go about this.

Comment: i think it's help for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092658/dynamic-positioned-hover-popup

Comment: This is not an efficient way though as I have to generate the definition each time,

Comment: I want to create a new file named definitions.php and have them all stored there and when any div with the name '.mp' is hovered then it shows the corresponding definition in a popup that is dynamically positioned below the '.mp' div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. You would have to generate the correct HTML in your PHP script.

```css
.tooltip-container {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 12px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #a6a6a6 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 15%;
}

.tooltip {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  padding: 10px;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.mp {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.mp:hover +.tooltip-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mp">
  <p>12.9</p>
</div>
<div class="tooltip-container">
  <span class="arrow-up"></span>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <h5>Hello World</h5>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, This is the effect I would like to achieve however '  <div class="tooltip-container">' has to be within the '.mp' div for this solution. I was hoping to have the same effect without having to generate a child div, instead the '  <div class="tooltip-container">' to be stored in a separate file that can be included in along with the definition on the hover of any div named '.mp'

Comment: I have adjusted the code. See if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try and implement this and let you know how I get on, thanks again

Comment: I have added the code here : http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php?compare_1=128

Comment: You can see only the small arrow shows not the full popup box

Comment: I can't find anything with a tooltip. Can you help?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the page, the tooltip is just above the footer on the link I sent cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php?compare_1=128

Comment: I have not changed the code you provided just copied it into the bottom of a page on the site, as you can see the popup does not show, just the arrow

Comment: You are setting the opacity of .tooltip to 0 in reset-text.less. The opacity should be 1 and the background color white.

Comment: I did not even realise, thank you, that must be something in bootstrap,i used !important to solve the issue. Thanks again for your help